# Responsive Flex Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I've created a responsive menu with a simple trigger using flexbox, but I've run into a problem.  Within one of the media queries, I drop the `UL` down below the `div` that contains the `logo` and the `trigger` and changed it's `display:none` until the trigger is clicked.

When I was trying to style `UL` for it's open state, when I gave it margin and padding, it increased the overall size of the `nav` so you could tell something was hiding.  Since the element is hidden, shouldn't the margin and padding have no effect until the open state is triggered?

I found a work around by adding margin and padding to the `LI` but I feel like that's a cheat.

```js
$(function() {
 
 $('.trigger').click(function() {
  $('.mainNav').toggleClass('show');
 });
 
 
});
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
}

body {
 font-size: 17px;
 color: white;
}

nav {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #333;
}

.nav-fixedWidth {
 height: inherit;
 min-height: 70px;
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row;
}

.logo-and-trigger {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
 content: '';
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 position: relative;
 margin: 8px 0;
}

.trigger {
 content: '';
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 display: none;
 position: relative;
 margin: 8px 0;
}

.mainNav{
 display: flex;
 width: 200px;
 justify-content: space-between;
 margin: 20px 0px;
 margin-left: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
 transition:max-height .3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
 
 .nav-fixedWidth {
  width: 100vw;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
 
 .nav-fixedWidth {
  flex-flow: column; 
 }
 
 .mainNav {
  margin:0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  max-height: 0;
 }
 
 .mainNav li {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
 }
 
 .show {
  max-height: 20em;
 }
 
 .trigger {
  display: flex;
 }
 
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
 <div class="nav-fixedWidth">
  <div class="logo-and-trigger">
   <div class="logo"></div>
   <div class="trigger"></div>
  </div>
  <ul class="mainNav">
   <li>Link 1</li>
   <li>Link 2</li>
   <li>Link 3</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: _"Since the element is hidden"_ - it isn't, you just gave it a max-height of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when you use "$('.mainNav').toggleClass('show');", you don't change UL to display:none so a space is allocated for UL on the page even if the trigger is not clicked. That's why you can see margin and padding on UL element.

If you want to keep toggleClass, you can apply margin and padding on the CSS class .show

Or if you want to add margin and padding on UL, you have to use $('.mainNav').css({'display':'block'}) and $('.mainNav').css({'display':'none'}) and don't use toggleClass.